# Where realistically could somebody be stabbed and heal without modern medicine?

Tags: internal-consistency, combat, medicine

Assuming we are in post-apocalyptic wilderness where herbs are readily available for treatment, would it be feasible for someone to be stabbed with a knife and not only survive but heal enough to keep moving within a week max? The wound can be anywhere, but I was thinking the only place it could realistically be is the upper arm around the bicep.

Comment: Too few details.  Shallow wound?  Thin knife like a stiletto?  Hits muscle?  Fat? Certainly not if an organ is hit, or any sizeable vein.  But, this is fiction, right?  In the movie *[Cloverfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloverfield)* a character lands on a piece of rebar, ran her through, she ran around like a healthy rabit for the rest of the movie (reality: she'd have bled out in less than 20 minutes, maybe less).

Comment: @JBH The knife would most likely be something like a steak knife and i believe would go through mostly fat and muscle, no bones or organs involved. It is fiction and if its not super realistic thats totally fine.

Comment: While ZioByte's answer is good, don't be too hasty marking a question answered.  People visit this site from around the world and generally, the moment you accept an answer people stop offering new answers.  You never know what you might learn.  We recommend waiting at least 24 hours before accepting an answer to give everyone time to chime in.

Comment: as the others had pointed out, it depends on the location and severity of the wound. Our body must maintain a certain level of blood pressure to ensure oxygen and other nutrients are transported to the cells to function properly, too much blood loss can be fatal and wound heals by introducing new cells which is glued in place with collagen... a painfully slow process by then bacteria and virus starts proliferating!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A stab with a clean blade may not be fatal and heal almost perfectly, even without modern medicine and outer help, if the blade travels only through skin, fat and muscle, possibly cutting some vein, but no major arteries.

If anything else is in its trajectory things get stingy, unless you have a doctor available.

A modern E.R. is not necessary (but it helps); doctors in Magna Grecia were perfectly able to help non-desperate cases and so were western doctors even before the invention of antibiotics.

A stab in the guts would have been almost certainly fatal.

In post-apocalyptic settings you can assume the presence of "doctors" akin to what they had in the Far West, I presume.

Comment: would you agree that given the situation you describe, the wounded person could be moving again in a week?

Comment: @JBH That sounds fairly acceptable provided the right healing plants are available at the time.

Comment: @JBH: it is unclear what you ask. In the first hypothesis (just muscle tissue) he would be moving (being careful) in a day. In "doctor needed" case it strongly depends on what was cut exactly, but, unless there are broken bones, which take time (~35 days) to heal (but patient is at least partly functional), I would say that if he is not somewhat on his feet in about a week he will die. Infections without antibiotics either resolve themselves relatively quickly or are fatal. A week is probably short, but not too much.

Comment: @ZioByte, I like your answer, but it doesn't address the OP's condition that the wounded person be capable of moving in a week.

Comment: "you can assume the presence of "doctors" akin to what they had in the Far West"

I stronhly disagree with you there, by post-apo we can guess a lot of the technolgy is gone, but the science, the knowledge, some people still have it and can teach it. So you would have farwest-like tools, but before-apo knowledge

Comment: @AlexandreAudin: as always much depends on specific settings and OP does not specify. In many post-apocalyptic settings knowledge is, at least partly, gone. IMHO you overestimate the power of "pure knowledge" and underestimate knowledge of ancient medics. Today's generic M.D. has *less* general knowledge *in his/her head* than one century ago as he relies heavily on lab analysis, specialists and on-line knowledge (all things which won't be available). Ancient doctors did a very good job in First Aid, given available resources. In other fields (geriatrics, gynecology) you would be very right.

Comment: @ZioByte You're the one speaking about medics. I recognize the power of ancient medicine and curative power of some plants. What i'm syaing is that (even if it's all up to the OP) most of the knowledge can be kept, even in realy devastated worlds ppl often find old books, etc...
And less global knowledge is smth, but don't forget it's less global knowledge about better understood problems soooo... I'd still rather have to face a actual doctor than a western one.

Comment: @AlexandreAudin: I suspect we are speaking we are speaking about two different things (and I'm unsure this is the place to discuss them, perhaps we should move to chat). I'm pessimist about knowledge permanence. I'm married with a MD and all medical books she has are the one she used to get her degree. Further information has been found online. This is true for many things and professions. Most of printed books are generic and have "detailed instructions" online; in my profession I get docs after NDA in electronic form with *prohibition* to print them (as if I would" they are thousand pages).

Answer (score 4):

A stab to the face (save the eyes) or scalp won't hinder your character's ability to run or use the arms. Sure the scalp bleeds like stink, but you know, that's what cautery irons are for. If blood loss isn't too great, could be running around within an hour or two.

Regardless of where the stab is, the primary factors in play will be luck and even more luck. A (relatively) clean wound that is quickly irrigated with (relatively) clean water and treated with (relatively) clean instruments and bandages will heal well enough on its own.

Getting up and moving again --- that will largely depend on how dire the need is to get up and move again. If your character is on the run or otherwise needs to get from one place to another, well, she'll get up and move.

So "realistically", your character can be stabbed just about anywhere that does not involve a great vessel or vital organ or needed tendon (Achilles tendon, anyone?) and heal without a well equipped modern ER / OR. People have been stabbing each other, biting each other, being attacked by predators and so forth for millennia and for some reason we still seem to be around as a species. Healing may not be ideal without proper care, but it does happen.

Comment: @Makyen -- point taken.

Answer (score 4):

A relatively short and skinny blade would be the best tool to get stabbed with.

You'll want to avoid organs, so the abdomen is out. The arm would be a good place like someone suggested. Possibly the character was trying to protect another part of his body and blocked the knife with his arm or fore arm. As long as you avoid the under arm area, because that's where major arteries run and if those are punctured it would most likely mean death.

The thigh is another good place. It's thick with muscle and being pierced with a smaller blade would probably be just a surface wound. The back of the leg though has major arteries and nerves that, if damaged, would require more than home treatments to fix. I also suggest looking at human anatomy diagrams to find ideal places to put this stab wound.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!